# Dependency Injection - passing parameters to constructed types

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm introducing Dependency Injection to my project. I've got a dialog window, which serves as an editor to either new or existing entity. Its ViewModel looks like the following:

```
public class ContractWindowViewModel
{
    private IRepository<Contract> contractRepository;
    private Contract model;
    private bool isNew;

    public ContractWindowViewModel(Contract contract, IRepository<Contract> contractRepository)
    {
        if (contract == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contract));
        if (contractRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contractRepository));

        this.contractRepository = contractRepository;
        this.model = contract;
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    public ContractWindowViewModel(IRepository<Contract> contractRepository)
    {
        this.contractRepository = contractRepository;
        this.model = new Contract();
        this.isNew = true;
    }

    // (...)
}
```

The plan is to inject `IRepository<Contract>`. But sometimes I need to pass `Contract` to the ViewModel (if I want to edit an existing one) or not (if I want to create new one). How should I do that using Unity?

Comment: You need to be able to create this view model later while the application is running, right? for example when the user clicks some button? Maybe based on which button the user has clicked, you will determine which constructor to call, right?

Comment: Instead of having your ViewModel speak to the repository directly, shouldn't you make it depend on the `Contract` class only? Why do you need to know if the `Contract` is new?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sure, but the button click handler will call `unityContainer.Resolve<ContractWindowViewModel>()`. How can I pass parameter through that construct?

Comment: The source of your problems is that you inject runtime data (the `Contract` instance) into the constructor of you components (the `ContractWindowViewModel` in this case). Your object graphs should be stateless, and runtime data should be passed through an existing object graph using method calls. Any time you violate that idea, you make everything much harder (as you are already experiencing). So instead of injecting the `Contract` using the constructor, define a method on your view model that allows setting the existing contract.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the DI container from your code (e.g. in a button event handler) is called Service Location and [is considered to be an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

You should instead have an factory that allows you to create your view model from inside your button handler (or your ViewModel command).

Here is an example of a factory:

```
public interface IContractWindowViewModelFactory
{
    ContractWindowViewModel CreateForNewContract();

    ContractWindowViewModel CreateForExistingContract(Contract existing_contract);
}

public class ContractWindowViewModelFactory : IContractWindowViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly IRepository<Contract> m_Repository;

    public ContractWindowViewModelFactory(IRepository<Contract> repository)
    {
        m_Repository = repository;
    }

    public ContractWindowViewModel CreateForNewContract()
    {
        return new ContractWindowViewModel(m_Repository);
    }

    public ContractWindowViewModel CreateForExistingContract(Contract existing_contract)
    {
        return new ContractWindowViewModel(existing_contract, m_Repository);
    }
}
```

Now you need to inject `IContractWindowViewModelFactory` into the class that needs to be able to create the `ContractWindowViewModel` view model (e.g. via constructor injection).

Since you are using a DI container, you need to register `IContractWindowViewModelFactory` with `ContractWindowViewModelFactory` in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). You also need to register `IRepository<Contract>` (which I am guessing you have already done).

Now, inside your button handler (or command handler), you can use the factory to create a `ContractWindowViewModel` for a new or existing `Contract`.

If for some reason, you still want to use the container from the button handler (which I encourage you **not** to do), then you can use [named registrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853(v=pandp.20).aspx) like this:

In your composition root:

```
container.RegisterType<ContractWindowViewModel>(
    "ForNew",
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IRepository<Contract>>()));

container.RegisterType<ContractWindowViewModel>(
    "ForExisting",
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<Contract>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IRepository<Contract>>()));
```

In your handler, you can use this for new contracts:

```
var viewmodel_for_new = container.Resolve<ContractWindowViewModel>("ForNew");
```

Or this for existing contracts:

```
Contract existing_contract = ...
var viewmodel_for_existing = container.Resolve<ContractWindowViewModel>(
    "ForExisting",
    new ParameterOverride("contract", existing_contract));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this...

```
unityContainer.Resolve<ContractWindowViewModel>(
    new ResolverOverride[] {
        new ParameterOverride("contract", new Contract()),
        new ParameterOverride("contractRepository", new Repository<Contract>())
    });
```

Source
http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/unity-passing-constructor-parameters-to-resolve